# Package Visual C++ Redistributable 2013 Binaries with App

Tags: wpf, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

A prerequiste of my WPF app is Visual C++ Redistributable 2013 to be installed on the machine.

Instead of having the user have to install the executable below I'd like to just package the binaries along with my App.

How can I get at these DLLs?

I shouldn't have to download/install a copy of VS2013 in order to get at them do I?

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [VC++ 2013 runtime redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40784) package. Microsoft publishes these C++ runtime redists explicitly for this purpose.

Bundle the one for your target architecture and run it automatically during installation. It's only a few MB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... however I already included the link in my post above. I'm explicitly not looking for the user to have to install the package. I just want the DLLs included along with my app.

Comment: You can deploy the C/C++ Runtime application local per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: @aherrick: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood. I didn't follow the link in your question since I thought you were referring to the entire Visual Studio 2013 installer, not just the VC++ runtime redist.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thanks... this seems like what I need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah(v=vs.120).aspx However where can I find those DLLs once the runtime redist is installed?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing the `VC++ 2013 runtime redistributable` on the machine and searched through `c:\windows\system32` for the following binaries:

- msvcr120.dll
- msvcp120.dll
- mfc120.dll
- mfc120u.dll
- mfcm120.dll
- mfcm120u.dll

Including those with my app worked!